# How to fix "Retryable write with txnNumber 9 is prohibited on session ..." on MongoDB session?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, transactions

I using Mongoose, NodeJS to connect to mongo.
My function has multiple operations like insert, update. To make sure data is consistence, I used mongo session, but sometime, I got an error with message `Retryable write with txnNumber 9 is prohibited on session xxxx - xxxx because a newer retryable write with txnNumber 11 has already started on this session.`

Here my code example:

```
aysnc function createDevice () {
  const session = await mongoose.startSession();

  try {
    const aCreated = await collectionA.create({}, { session });
    const bCreated = await collectionB.create({}, { session });
    await collectionA.updateOne({ _id: aCreated._id }, { $set: { bId: bCreated._id }}, { session });
    // and some operation in a parallel process
    await Promise.all([
      collectionC.create({}, { session }),
      collectionD.update({}, {}, { session })
    ]);
  } catch (err) {

  } final {
    await session.endSession();
  }
}
```

I can't reproduce where/how the issue happened?

Comment: sessions are not thread safe. I assume the issue is related to `Promise.all` steps. Just a guess, I'm not really familiar with node

Comment: @dodod Thanks for drop the comment, I guessed so, I separated Promise.all to single promise and continue monitor.